# Mask input (example - password) in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have three path variables for an API. I want to mask one input on Swagger UI with *****.

How can I do this when using Springdoc OpenAPI?

Answer (score 9):

You just use the swagger annotations:

```
@Parameter(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "password"))
```

Answer (score 1):

As already shown by [jenkinsme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13640954/jenkinsme) in their answer, set the *format* to `password`. Also, the *type* field is not needed as it defaults to string (hopefully all passwords are strings).

```java
@Parameter(schema = @Schema(format = "password"))
```

The above will show up as shown in the below image

[image]

Refer the OpenAPI specification page on [Data Types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/) for all the supported types

Comment: how to implement this into openapi 3 ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "implement this into openapi3"?

Comment: I have added this, "@Parameter(schema = @Schema(format = "password")) @RequestParam String password) "
this is working but in swagger, password text field input size lessor in compare of string format

Comment: What do you mean by "password text field input size lessor in compare of string format"?

Comment: I mean, I have another string input field in swagger, next to password but in the GUI, text field size is differ, String input field is longer size then password one which is above in picture.

Answer (score 0):

Using YAML for generating code from OpenAPI 3 documentation:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
        username:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
          format: password
        givenName:
          type: string
        familyName:
          type: string
        address:
          type: string
      required:
        - id
        - username
        - password
        - givenName
        - familyName
        - address
```

Note, that `type: string` is not necessary for password, since `format: password` already implies it, but I like to keep there just the same.